# error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c++

here is some codes that I want to find the desired substring block in a string:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

...
unsigned int stage = 3;
string::iterator iter = s.begin();
string::iterator iter_next = s.end();

for (unsigned int i=0; i<stage; i++) {

    iter = std::find(iter, s.end(),"#STAGE");

}
    iter_next = std::find(iter, s.end(), "#STAGE");

string sub = string(iter, iter_next);
...
```

I chose returning iterator instead of index. However, debug give me this :

```
error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer. 

c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:-1: 
In function '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, 
const _Tp&, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator =   
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > >, _Tp = char [7]]':
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\bits\stl_algo.h:4224: instantiated  
from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = 
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> > >, _Tp = char [7]]'
```

Everything is fine when I used index method. I understand it must be a simple mistake but I hope someone can point out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
iter = std::find(iter, s.end(),"#STAGE");
```

It's wrong. You cannot find `string` in `string`, using `std::find`. Only character.

You can simply use

```
size_t pos = s.find("#STAGE");
```

and create iterator by

```
iter = s.begin() + pos;
```

if `pos` is not equal to `std::string::npos`.

Answer (score 1):

A `std::string` iterator iterates over characters, not strings.

If you want to look for `"#STAGE"` in your string, simply use :

```
s.find("#STAGE");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 iter = std::find(iter, s.end(),"#STAGE");
```

`std::find` tries to compare a `char`(promoted to `int`) and a `const char*` (#STAGE)

`find` works on **value types** of containers. In string case that is a `char`. So you can not use it to find a `string` in a `string`.

For example this is valid.

```
 iter = std::find(iter, s.end(), 'A');
```

---

Use [string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) instead

```
size_t pos = s.find("#STAGE");
```